# Origin of NSButton is not updating

Tags: swift, macos, animation, nsbutton

I have a few buttons on the screen and they need to move with animation.
I update the origin of button in the loop but my frames only updated at the end of the for loop. Only showing movement from first point to the last one, ignoring all the iteration frames.
Here is my code:

```
    var origin = btn.frame.origin
    let diff = pos - btn.currPosition

    print("initial pos : \(origin)\n")
    print("diff : \(diff)\n")

    for move in 1...diff {
       // some calculations for movement, then
        btn.animator().setFrameOrigin(origin)
        btn.currPosition = position

    }
```

Can anyone please tell when a view redraw itself? I have used setNeedsDisplay() and display() calls to redraw but it's working only after loop is completed.

Comment: then the problem is in iteration, perhaps 'diff' should be of different Type? convert to Int? Create an array of positions with specified space between?

Comment: iteration is fine. It's changing the frame but that change is not updating in the UI. I have tried to Dispatch the code of setting frame synchronously but with no luck.

Comment: self.view.reloadInputViews() inside the loop?

Comment: Unable to use that as it's mac application, not UIButton

Comment: NSButton inherits from NSControl -> NSView - so try .updateLayer() ?

Comment: .updateLayer() is of no effect. I tried.

Comment: Are you running the code on a thread?

Comment: it's on main thread